# Modify React Element From React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

**Live Preview**: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KoSqF5OB0IRtbBEi822

Im trying to Clone and Modify a React Element Object.

*I'm removing the inline styles of react element by cloning and adding css rules to stylesheet*

Im using this [**function**](https://gist.github.com/dsslimshaddy/5e89f5fd115ee587d8b4d8647b7832a6)

I want to know how can i access the React Render function return value from the Element's Class ?

```
const Div = () => (<div></div>); // not working
const Div = (<div></div>); // working

const NewDiv = noInline(Div); // calling function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to do it you need to get a reference to the element in the `render` function, and that element should be one of the component child elements — so traverse `this.props.children` and find the element you are looking for. Something like this:

```
render () {
  let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
  children.forEach((child) => doSomething(child))
}
```